# Block Devices & Partitions

Tags: partition, devices, block-device, disk

I partitioned a microSD card (`mmcblk1`) into two partitions `mmcblk1p1` and `mmcblk1p2`.

If use a dedicated card reader I am able to see the entire SD card and its partitions using various disk management tools on my PC.

I am able to mount both partitions on my Android phone. However when I put my phone into USB Mass Storage mode, only `mmcblk1p1` appears as a drive letter on my computer. `mmcblk1p2` remains mounted and usable on the phone.

1. Isn't the partition table (GPT or MBR) stored outside of `mmcblk1p1` and thus not accessible to the computer?
2. Assuming (1) how does the computer clearly show a disk with only 1 partition in various disk management tools as if it was a physical disk? Is the phone's Mass Storage mode performing some kind of abstraction?
3. What exactly would happen if I partitioned this disk on the computer? Would the phone then see a new `mmcblk1p3`. How would it even be possible without access to the real partition table?

Comment: I've been wondering about the same thing since I got a Droid Bionic with a 16GB MicroSD card - it shows up as two 8GB partitions in Android, one of which is inaccessible to a lot of apps, and a single 16GB disk when mounted on anything else. I haven't taken the time to research it but I'll keep this question in mind if I do.

Comment: The USB Mass Storage mode of the system probably isn't just a straight forwarder between the USB cable and the memory card - it probably takes the first partition and serves it as a block device to the other side of the USB cable.

Comment: @peterph Yes it's presenting the first partition as a block device over USB Mass Storage, but where is the partition table coming from for Windows to recognise the drive? Is Windows simply reading a raw partition beginning from block 0? In that case partitioning the drive on Windows should result in a nested MBR and will render the partition corrupt within Android. Can someone confirm?

Comment: I would expect exactly that.